# How to count date occurences pandas ?[python]

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new with pandas and I have a column: "Date" which contains several occurrences, from a csv file :
I want them in order, regrouped by day(so no more occurrence) and able to create a  column with occurrence number: "OccPerDay"
example I have this column:

```
Date
30-Jan-2014 
10-Jan-2014 
20-Jan-2014 
10-Jan-2014 
10-Jan-2014 
20-Jan-2014 
15-Jan-2014
```

I want :

```
Date                   OccPerDay
10-Jan-2014            3 
15-Jan-2014            1
20-Jan-2014            2
30-Jan-2014            1
```

here is my code:

```
        df = df.groupby('Date', as_index=False)['Date'].value_counts()
        df["OccPerDay"]= ??? # Im lost
        print(df[["Date", "OccPerDay"]])
```

but it doesn't work :(   I'm lost can someone help me?

Comment: Like this: `df.groupby(["Date"]).size().reset_index(name='OccPerDay')`

Comment: @drec4s Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for since hours. I continue to improve skills and understand your command.